# Proof of an accelerated expansion of the universe

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, redshift, bao

Are there any more "proofs" of an accelerated expansion of the universe other than:

$1:$ that galaxies that are farther away from us are also more redshifted.

$2:$ using "Baryon acoustic oscillations" to compare the sound horizon today with the sound horizon at the time of decoupling (using the CMB)?

Comment: There are details in the red shifts such as absorption lines from intergalactic hydrogen dust that would be hard to explain if not for universal expansion

Comment: I mean proof for accelerated expansion, not expansion. I realize my title was misleading. I appreciate the answer though!

Comment: I assume you mean 'evidence for' or 'argument for', rather than 'proof'?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if you know this already but your point 1 is unclear.

More distant galaxies being more red shifted  than closer ones is evidence of expansion, not accelerated expansion. Uniform expansion would give this too. The evidence for accelerated expansion is that the relationship is not linear at greater distances. The redshift is actually less than you might expect for the more distant galaxies relative to their measured distance.

This article gives a good overview:
https://www.pnas.org/content/96/8/4224